# Symfony2 twig translate variable values in {% trans %} tag

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and have a question from it.
In one **twig** template I receive a variable from controller. It's a string and I need to translate it. But the syntax

```
{% trans %}{{ post['name'] }}{% endtrans %}
```

returns error "A message must be a simple text in...".

So is there a way to translate the variable values???

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [filters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#twig-templates):

```
{{ post['name']|trans }}
```