# twig translations work partially which syntax to use is not clear

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

```
{# this dont work  #}
{% trans %}Hello%name%!{% endtrans %}
{# this dont work  #}
{% trans with {'%name%':name} %}Hello%name%!{% endtrans %}
```

Did a bit of searching and found that translatioon has problems with spaces
I have removed spaces after Hello 
[Symfony2+Twig, variable in translation return "A message must be a simple text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811162/symfony2twig-variable-in-translation-return-a-message-must-be-a-simple-text)
[Symfony2 twig translate variable values in {% trans %} tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632502/symfony2-twig-translate-variable-values-in-trans-tag) 
[How to translate with pluralization in Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384745/how-to-translate-with-pluralization-in-twig)

this works

```
{{ 'Hello' | trans }} {{ name }}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
   <body>
     <trans-unit id="191">
     <source>Hello</source>
     <target>Ciao</target>
     </trans-unit>
   </body>
 </file>
</xliff>
```

so have to use Filters?

am using Symfony v2.4 + twig v1.15
Could someone Clarify?

TIA

Comment: Why do you remove the spaces? And please show us your messages file

Comment: @WouterJ All the above code is in a single html.twig so it works partially.. i havent included $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n()); dont know where to add that. envrionment.php maybe and change the inclusion to this $this->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n()) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be translated when you dont have a translation with `<source>Hello%name%</source>`

change it to this:

```
 {{ 'Hello'|trans({'%name%':'some name'}) }}

 <trans-unit id="191">
 <source>Hello</source>
 <target>Ciao %name%!</target>
 </trans-unit>
```

this should output `"Ciao some name!"`

Comment: thanks it works.. 
are you related to the Famous footballer.. just kidding ;)